# How to sum corresponding values on a data frame (in R)?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sum

Giving a common denominator (`Subject`) I need to find out the corresponding number of materials that satisfy a criterion: material type A (`blood`) was donated within 20 days before material type B (`bone_marrow`).

Say I have a data frame containing the following:

```
   Subject_ID    Material Date_of_donation
1   Subject_1       blood       01-03-2019
2   Subject_2       blood       01-10-2019
3   Subject_3       blood       02-05-2019
4   Subject_2 bone_marrow       02-09-2019
5   Subject_4       blood       02-10-2019
6   Subject_1 bone_marrow       03-07-2019
7   Subject_2 bone_marrow       05-11-2019
8   Subject_2 bone_marrow       06-01-2019
9   Subject_4 bone_marrow       03-09-2019
10  Subject_1       blood       03-08-2019
11  Subject_1       blood       04-06-2019
12  Subject_3       blood       05-11-2019
13  Subject_4       blood       03-15-2019
14  Subject_2       blood       06-03-2019
15  Subject_1       blood       03-15-2019
16  Subject_4       blood       05-27-2019
17  Subject_5 bone_marrow       09-10-2019
18  Subject_5       blood       09-16-2019
```

Now, for each `Subject` I need to count, among all donations he/she performed, those that the `blood` was donated within 20 days prior to `bone_marrow` (and not otherwise). There is not necessarily the need to know which subjects donated within that time gap. Instead, a more generic count would do; something like this:

```
    blood_and_BM<=20_days     blood_and_BM>20_days
                     x                     y
```

How could one approach that?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Definitely not easy to build a reputation here. And it doesn't help much when, even though one follows the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), gets a downvote without any apparent reason.<\b> Anyways, this forum has great discussions, and it would help to get at least an indication of what is wrong with the question, so newcomers would be able to contribute more and feel less of a "hassle" to other users.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the issue, there are no subjects in the sample data who donated marrow within 20 days of donating blood. So I adjust the donations for Subjects 2 and 5 to satisfy the condition:

```
# ADJUSTED DATA
  df <-
    tribble(
      ~SubjectID,    ~Material, ~DateDonation,
      'Subject_1',       'blood',       '01-03-2019',
      'Subject_2',       'blood',       '02-08-2019',
      'Subject_3',       'blood',       '02-05-2019',
      'Subject_2', 'bone_marrow',       '02-09-2019',
      'Subject_4',       'blood',       '02-10-2019',
      'Subject_1', 'bone_marrow',       '03-07-2019',
      'Subject_2', 'bone_marrow',       '05-11-2019',
      'Subject_2', 'bone_marrow',       '06-01-2019',
      'Subject_4', 'bone_marrow',       '03-09-2019',
      'Subject_1',       'blood',       '03-08-2019',
      'Subject_1',       'blood',       '04-06-2019',
      'Subject_3',       'blood',       '05-11-2019',
      'Subject_4',       'blood',       '03-15-2019',
      'Subject_2',       'blood',       '06-03-2019',
      'Subject_1',       'blood',       '03-15-2019',
      'Subject_4',       'blood',       '05-27-2019',
      'Subject_5', 'bone_marrow',       '09-10-2019',
      'Subject_5',       'blood',       '09-06-2019'
    ) %>%
  #format date
    mutate(
      DateDonation = mdy(DateDonation),
      DonCount = n()
    )
```

Then create marrow--blood combinations:

```
# Marrow--blood combos
  df <-
    df %>% 

  # isolate blood donations
    filter(Material == 'blood') %>%

  # by Subject, pull blood dates into a list
    group_by(SubjectID) %>%
    mutate(
      bdates = list(DateDonation)
    ) %>%
    slice(1) %>% # drop repeats

  # merge to marrow dates
    select(SubjectID,bdates) %>%
    right_join(df) %>%
    filter(Material == 'bone_marrow') %>%

  # expand the list into columns
    unnest(bdates) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Then calculate the intervals and tally by the 20-day criteria:

```
# calculate intervals, tally
  df %>%
  # donated blood first
    filter(DateDonation > bdates) %>%
  # calculate period in days
    mutate(
      distance = time_length(interval(bdates,DateDonation), 'day')
    ) %>%
  # sum up and finalize
    mutate(
      under20 = sum(distance <= 20),
      over20 = DonCount - under20
    ) %>%
    select(under20,over20) %>%
    unique()
```

It returns the count you request:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  under20 over20
    <int>  <int>
1       2     16
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution, but I have none.

Answer (score 0):

I think about this as a timeline for each subject. Using `lag()` and `group_by()`, we can operate within the dataframe construct to quickly identify important milestones in the data for each subject, and then use filters to show only those subjects that meet the criteria. From there you'll have the detail of which subjects meet the criteria, which can easily be counted (i.e. via `nrow()`). Alternatively, instead of a filter, you could also create another variable which indicates if the criteria are met, then sum the total. I used 365 as a cutoff here so some results would show.

```
library(tidyverse)

data_string <-
"Subject_ID    Material Date_of_donation
Subject_1       blood       01-03-2019
Subject_2       blood       01-10-2019
Subject_3       blood       02-05-2019
Subject_2 bone_marrow       02-09-2019
Subject_4       blood       02-10-2019
Subject_1 bone_marrow       03-07-2019
Subject_2 bone_marrow       05-11-2019
Subject_2 bone_marrow       06-01-2019
Subject_4 bone_marrow       03-09-2019
Subject_1       blood       03-08-2019
Subject_1       blood       04-06-2019
Subject_3       blood       05-11-2019
Subject_4       blood       03-15-2019
Subject_2       blood       06-03-2019
Subject_1       blood       03-15-2019
Subject_4       blood       05-27-2019
Subject_5 bone_marrow       09-10-2019
Subject_5       blood       09-16-2019"

data <- read.table(text = data_string, header = TRUE) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Date_of_donation), lubridate::as_date)

material1 <- "blood"
material2 <- "bone_marrow"
days_cutoff <- 365

data2 <- data %>%
  group_by(Subject_ID) %>%
  mutate(
    # determine days between donations
    DaysSinceLastDonation = Date_of_donation-lag(Date_of_donation),

    # mark the donations of importance
    BloodToBMDonation = Material == material2 & lag(Material) == material1) %>%

  # find which subjects meet criteria
  filter(BloodToBMDonation & DaysSinceLastDonation <= days_cutoff)

data2
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   Subject_ID [2]
  Subject_ID Material    Date_of_donation DaysSinceLastDonation BloodToBMDonation
  <fct>      <fct>       <date>           <drtn>                <lgl>            
1 Subject_2  bone_marrow 0002-09-20       335 days              TRUE             
2 Subject_4  bone_marrow 0003-09-20       335 days              TRUE
```